# Extracting data from HTML using PHP and xPath

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, extract

I am trying to extract data from a webpage to insert it to a database. The data I'm interested in is in the div's which have a class="company". On one webpage there are 15 or less div's like that, and there are many pages I am trying to extract this data from. For this reason I am trying to find a automatic solution for data extraction.

The div with a class="company" is as follows (there are 15 or less divs like this on one page with different data):

```html
<div class="company" id="company-6666"> <!-- EXTRACT 'company-6666' from id="company-6666" -->

  <div class="top clearfix">
    <div class="name clearfix">
      <h2>
        <a href="/company-name">Company Name</a>&nbsp; <!-- EXTRACT 'Company Name' from contents of A element and EXTRACT '/company-name' from href attribute -->
        <a href="/branches-list-link?parent_id=6666" class="branches">Branches <span>(5)</span></a> <!-- EXTRACT '/branches-list-link?parent_id=6666' from href attribute -->               
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="inner clearfix has-logo">

    <div class="clearfix">          
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="/company-name">
          <img src="/graphics/company/logo/listing/123456.jpg?_ts=1365390237" border="0" alt="" /> <!-- EXTRACT '/graphics/company/logo/listing/123456.jpg?_ts=1365390237' from src attribute -->
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        <div class="address">StreetName 500, 7777 City, County</div> <!-- EXTRACT 'StreetName 500, 7777 City, County' from contents of class="address" div -->
        <div class="clearfix">
          <div class="slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac condimentum mi.</div> <!-- EXTRACT 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac condimentum mi.' from contents of class="slogan" div -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions-bar clearfix">
      <ul>              
        <li><span class="phone-number">6666666</span></li> <!-- EXTRACT '6666666' from contents of class="phone-number" div -->
        <li><a href="mailto:mail@mail.com" target="_blank" title="mail@mail.com" class="email">mail@mail.com</a></li> <!-- EXTRACT 'mail@mail.com' from contents of class="email" div -->
        <li><a href="http://www.webpage.com" target="_blank" title="www.webpage.com" class="redirect url">www.webpage.com</a></li> <!-- EXTRACT 'www.webpage.com' from contents of class="redirect url" div -->
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

So far I have the following PHP code (the $output has the webpage's HTML code):

```
<?php

$doc = new DomDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($output);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@class='company']");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        echo $element->nodeValue;
    }
}

?>
```

It seems that it gets all of the 15 div's with class="company" but I have no idea how to extract the previously mentioned (in comments of HTML code) individual values.

Every div (I am talking about the div with class="company") doesn't have all the values written in the HTML block. So somehow I have to make a query if a specific div inside the company div, where the data i'm interested in, exists and if it exists I have to check if it is not empty (contains text between tags or not). If it exists and is not empty I add it to a variable.

Once values are extracted I would like to assign them to PHP variables which let's me to work with them afterwards. It would be even better if the values extracted are put in array like so:

```
$result = array(
    // 1'st div's data
    [0] =>  
        'company name' => 'company name',
        'company link' => 'company link',
        'company id' => 'company id',
        'company branches'  => 'branches link',
        'company logo'  => 'logo',
        'company address'  => 'address',
        'company slogan'  => 'slogan',
        'company webpage'  => 'webpage',
        'company email'  => 'email',
        'company phone'  => 'phone'

    // 2'nd div's data
    [1] =>  
        'company name' => 'company name',
        'company link' => 'company link',
        'company id' => 'company id',
        'company branches'  => 'branches link',
        'company logo'  => 'logo',
        'company address'  => 'address',
        'company slogan'  => 'slogan',
        'company webpage'  => 'webpage',
        'company email'  => 'email',
        'company phone'  => 'phone'
    ...
    )
```

Comment: Waits for it... I know it's coming... who has "The answer" we all know what answer I mean!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each *Company* can be represented by a context-node while having each property represented by an xpath-expression relative to it:

```
Company company-6666:
 ->id ....... = "company-6666"    --    string(@id)
 ->name ..... = "Company Name"    --    .//a[1]/text()
 ->href ..... = "/company-name"    --    .//a[1]/@href
 ->img ...... = "/graphics/company/logo/listing/123456.jpg?_ts=1365390237"    --    .//img[1]/@src
 ->address .. = "StreetName 500, 7777 City, County"    --    .//*[@class="address"]/text()
 ...
```

If you wrap that into objects, this is pretty nifty to use:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

/* @var $companies DOMValueObject[] */
$companies = new Companies($doc);

foreach ($companies as $company) {
    printf("Company %s:\n", $company->id);
    foreach ($company->getObjectProperties() as $name => $value) {
        $expression = $company->getPropertyExpression($name);
        printf(" ->%'.-10s = \"%s\"    --    %s\n", $name.' ', $value, $expression);
    }
}
```

This works with *DOMObjectCollection* and *DOMValueObject*, defining your own type:

```
class Companies extends DOMValueCollection
{
    public function __construct(DOMDocument $doc) {
        parent::__construct($doc, '//*[@class="company"]');
    }

    /**
     * @return DOMValueObject
     */
    public function current() {
        $object = parent::current();
        $object->defineProperty('id', 'string(@id)');
        $object->defineProperty('name', './/a[1]/text()');
        $object->defineProperty('href', './/a[1]/@href');
        $object->defineProperty('img', './/img[1]/@src');
        $object->defineProperty('address', './/*[@class="address"]/text()');
        # ... add your definitions
        return $object;
    }
}
```

And for your array requirements there is a `getArrayCopy()` method:

```
echo "\nGet Array Copy:\n\n";

print_r($companies->getArrayCopy());
```

Output:

```
Get Array Copy:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => company-6666
            [name] => Company Name
            [href] => /company-name
            [img] => /graphics/company/logo/listing/123456.jpg?_ts=1365390237
            [address] => StreetName 500, 7777 City, County
        )

)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I put the DOMValueCollection and DOMValueobject class definitions into separate php file but when checking for errors it told me: 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /class.php on line 24`
It is this row: `$this->definitions[$name] = [$expression, $default];`

Comment: @Robert: That is likely because you're not using PHP 5.4. But 5.4 is not required, take a look at the updated gist.

Comment: You were right. My PHP version is 5.3.23, but with your updated classes it works flawlessly. But anyways Thank YOU Very Much!!! This is exactly the solution I was looking for and I got more help than I hoped for. :)

Answer (score 1):

To check if a node exists, verify that the length property is equal to 1 in the returned query result:

```
if ($company_name->length == 1) {
   $object->company_name = trim($company_name->item(0)->nodeValue);
}
```