# XPath query return multiple nodes on different levels

Tags: php, xml, xpath

PHP XPath query:

```
$query = $xpathvar->query('//siri:Service');
foreach($query as $service) {
    echo $service->textContent;
    // Here I need to also echo this Vehicle's reg
}
```

Targeted XML:

```
<Vehicle>
    <CategoryA>
        <Service>123123123</Service>
    </CategoryA>
    <CategoryB>
         <SubCategoryA>
             <Reg>ASDF_XC1</Reg>
         </SubCategoryA>
    </CategoryB>
</Vehicle>
// Imagine many more vehicles here each with a service and reg
```

How can I alter the PHP so that I also retrieve the Reg for each one as well? The Service and Reg have to be inside the same Vehicle when retrieved (not random pairs).

Comment: Your question is not really clear. According to the XML structure, the Reg should be part of `textContent` already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about querying vehicle and then using it as context node to search for `Service` and `Reg`?

```
$vehicles = $xpath->query('//siri:Vehicle');
$pairs = array();
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    $pairs[] = array(
        'Service' => $xpath->evaluate('string(.//siri:Service)', $vehicle),
        'Reg'     => $xpath->evaluate('string(.//siri:Reg)'    , $vehicle),
    );
}
```

See as well:

- [Combining two Xpaths into one loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19052864/367456)